# PhpStorm 2017.2.4: highlight matching parentheses on selection

Tags: phpstorm

I've been searching for the Code Style setting to highlight the opening and closing parenthesis on selection.

Here is an image of an example using the theme WarmNeon:
[image]

I'm using my own edited version of the Solarized Light theme but I just can't find this particular setting: I searched on highlight, parenthesis and went through the settings manually to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Color Scheme | General`
3. `Code | Matched brace`

[image]